# ¿Cómo recuperar los datos de las relaciones entre entidades después de guardar en Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Estoy iniciando con Spring Framework donde trato de construir un Servicio Web REST utilizando Spring Boot y Spring Data JPA (donde me he estancado).
Tengo 2 objetos, *Persona* y *Usuario*, donde la entidad *Usuario* tiene un objeto de tipo *Persona* que representa la relación entre estas entidades. El inconveniente es que cuando guardo un *Usuario* me devuelve todos los datos de la entidad *Persona* con **null** y no es ese el comportamiento que estoy buscando.


Para un mejor contexto, el código en cuestión es el siguiente:

#### Persona:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONAS")
public class Persona {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String dni;

    @Column
    private String nombre;

    @Column
    private String apellido;

    //Getter, setter y constructores
}
```

#### Usuario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIOS")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nombre_usuario")
    private String nombreUsuario;

    @Column(name = "clave_usuario")
    private String claveUsuario;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "persona_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Persona persona;

    //Getter, setter y constructores
}
```

#### Repositorio, servicio y controlador:

```
@Repository
public class UsuarioRepository {

    @Autowired
    //Interfaz que hereda de JpaRepository
    private UsuarioCrudRepository usuarioCrudRepository;

    public Usuario saveUser(Usuario usuario) {
        return usuarioCrudRepository.saveAndFlush(usuario);
    }

    public Optional<Usuario> findUser(long id) {
        return usuarioCrudRepository.findById(id);
    }

}

@Service
public class UsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    public Usuario save(Usuario usuario) {
        return usuarioRepository.saveUser(usuario);
    }

    public Usuario find(Long id) {
        Optional<Usuario> usuario = usuarioRepository.findUser(id);
        if (usuario.isPresent()) {
            return usuario.get();
        } else {
            return new Usuario();
        }
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@CrossOrigin
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @PostMapping()
    public Usuario save(@RequestBody Usuario u) {
        return usuarioService.save(u);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{usuarioId}")
    public Usuario findById(@PathVariable("usuarioId") long id){
        return usuarioService.find(id);
    }

}
```

Utilizando [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) le paso los datos a la API de la siguiente manera:

```
{
    "nombreUsuario": "nickUser",
    "claveUsuario": "12345",
    "persona": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

Pero la respuesta que obtengo es:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombreUsuario": "nickUser",
    "claveUsuario": "12345",
    "persona": {
        "id": 1,
        "dni": null,
        "nombre": null,
        "apellido": null
    }
}
```

Lo que traté de hacer entonces fue en el controlador utilizar el otro método que busca a un *Usuario* por su id, pero para mi sorpresa, aún me devuelve todos los datos de la persona con **null** solo si es **inmediatamente después de la inserción**. Lo que más me llama la atención es que tengo activado la propiedad para que se muestren las consultas SQL por consola (`spring.jpa.show-sql=true`) pero al ejecutar el método `findUser` del repositorio no aparece la consulta correspondiente por consola (aclaro que esto solo sucede después de insertar un nuevo *Usuario*).

Comment: Puedes agregar el Código de la clase UsuarioCrudRepository, lo normal fuese que `UsuarioRepository` implementara la interfaz.

Answer (score 0):

> Utilizando Postman le paso los datos a la API de la siguiente manera:

El problema es al guardar el usuario:

```json
{
    "nombreUsuario": "nickUser",
    "claveUsuario": "12345",
    "persona": {
        "id": 1,
        // te faltan los otros campos de la persona
    }
}
```

No estás enviando los datos de la persona, dni, nombre y apellido.

Cuando haces:

```java
public Usuario save(Usuario usuario) {
  return usuarioRepository.saveUser(usuario);
}
```

El objeto usuario que envias tiene null los datos dni, nombre y apellido.

Es por eso que en la respuesta obtienes:

> Pero la respuesta que obtengo es:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombreUsuario": "nickUser",
    "claveUsuario": "12345",
    "persona": {
        "id": 1,
        "dni": null,
        "nombre": null,
        "apellido": null
    }
}
```

La primer solución es enviar en el json los datos de la persona que faltan.

Otra solución es que al guardar un usuario, hagas una búsqueda por `id` de persona y añadas los datos al objeto usuario.

Algo como:

```java
@Service
public class UsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PersonaRepository personaRepository;

    public Usuario save(Usuario usuario) {
        Persona persona = personaRepository.findById(usuario.getPersona().getId()); // acá obviamente debes validar que exista y ver que hacer si no existe. (Depende de tus reglas de negocio)
        usuario.setPersona(persona);
        return usuarioRepository.saveUser(usuario);
    }

}
```

Comment: Tengo este mismo problema a la fecha. Con tu solucion tengo una duda. Tengo un metood que en el @Query ya recupera todo correcto con un inner join, y tengo un endpoint para consultar solo un registro por id. Para no hacerlo manual, en mi caso abajo del save llamo al metodo getInfoByID donde en teoria ya se tendria que setterar todo., pero no pasa. Sabes si las transacciones tienen algo que ver?

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontré yo fue hacer un Request que es como un modelo son declarar el @entity agregándole todos los getters y setters pero en las relaciones poniéndole como un Long ejemplo: userId
Y luego en el controlador haciendo una función que transforme los datos del modelo a los datos del request

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).